# Which is the best approach for Laying down the text on first scroll of the website?

Tags: website-design, hierarchy, typography, product-design, anchors

[image]The wireframes are for a product website, which is a suite of online products that can be used together or as individual modules.

**Option1** has a traditional HEADING-BODY COPY approach. The most common way we perceive website content in general, Where the heading is the emotional hook. While the body copy acts as a basic product descriptor.

**Option2** has a straight forward approach with 1-2 line descriptor, and highlighting the key point in the product. 
The reason for creating this approach is

1) It is a product website which is a suite of online products that can be used together or as individual modules.Which means any user will actually end up on the website with an intention while researching rather than just random googeling.

2) Which means, he is consciously aware to some degree what sort of product he needs.

3) Which means he has gone through many websites, even if not too many at least 3-4.

4) Which means he is aware of the fancy filler content that people put up on website to make it look good.

5) So to stand apart and to grab users attention or to anchor him to the product,  a straight forward approach with less content and that to in a single font style and an illustration is a better option

6) So he can just read one line and get a gist about the product, with a highlighted point and start exploring the product

Comment: What's the question?  What does "laying down the text on first scroll" mean for the two options??

Comment: " Laying down the text on first scroll" I mean the way text is styled on each option. For the first opening fold of website home page

Comment: I mean the way text is stylized in both of the options for the first opening fold of website

Answer (score 1):

I would like you to go with the 1  type of approach.

I totally understand your reasons with which you are backing up the second approach, but i find it bit uncomfortable to accept it.

1. when you consider the first point of yours, it's not necessary that as a user must end up with whole lot of research and then end up in the website, ***most of the people what ever they want they first search with the vague idea about the product.***
2. When we speak about the second point, let's consider a situation if the product is a car, ***it's not necessary for the user to know about the car, except the brand and the model name.***
3. The third point of yours makes sense, but consider that what if, the website what you are building is the first website surfed by the user to know about the product, if it is not clear enough he will skip the website and goes to next website. ***" it is always not necessary that user must go through 3 - 4 websites to visit the website you build"***
4. Kindly don't assume that all user will be smart enough that the user will skip the fancy filler, ***if you consider the world famous product all are bought at-least once by everyone because of the aesthetics (appearance).***
5. Considering the fifth point of yours, using the single font is fine, but ***there must be some prioritisation in the content in order to show the user which is important for the user and getting more attention***, which is shown either by using the font alterations such as Bold, italics, Underline or changing colour (Highlights).
6. Final point is acceptable, which applies for the approach 1

Creating website of a product is an extension of the product which is a face for the product where user will interact, if the face is not good or not attractive none will respond properly, unless when people know about the product already.